# I am trying to get privately provided contours to be recognized by arcmap as such

Tags: autocad, arcmap

I have a contour map that is provided to me by a private company. it comes in the form of a .dwg that works for autocad. In the past i have gotten contour data from usgs but the data provided to me is much more accurate. I want these contours in the .dwg to get loaded into arcmap so I can use them to delineate watersheds as per usual procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open .dwg file from ArcMap's add data option, locate the .dwg file, double click on it and it will show you it's sub-files, open Polyline file or any other file from it as u desire.

Then you can create its boundary and DEM to carry out your tasks.